# How do I create Multiple bootstrap dropdown menus per page that don't interact with each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the following code I use the first bootstrap dropdown to list a selection of items to show. Selecting one creates a bootstrap nav bar with two input fields, a check in field, another dropdown button and two additional buttons. I've put it together like you see in the below example. 
The problem is the selection I make in the first dropdown appears in the second dropdown as the title, and that dropdown does not work to give the additional options.

I can't seem to find a way to keep the two dropdown button items from clashing, how can I make them independent of each other?

```
<div id="container">
<div id="select1" class="dropdown">

    <button id="dpbutton" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> Select an Existing Net
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href = "#" onclick = "showActivities('0')">Show All Stations in DB</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li role='presentation' class=' bg-success ' data-value="13"'>
        <a href='#' role='menuitem' onclick = 'showActivities(13)'>
            Item1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li role='presentation' class=' bg-success ' data-value="12"'>
        <a href='#' role='menuitem' onclick = 'showActivities(12)'>
            Item2
        </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<nav id="admin" class=" hidden navbar navbar-inverse admin flashit roundit" role="navigation">
    <div class=" container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
          <div class="form-group">

            <input id="cs1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Call Sign"  tabindex=1 onkeyup="showHint(this.value);"  maxlength="16" onmousedown="isKeyPressed(event)" autofocus />

            <input id="Fname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" tabindex=2 onkeyup="nameHint(this.value);" onblur="checkIn();" />

          </div>
        </form>

        <button id="ckin2" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" tabindex=3  >Check In</button>


        <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="showops" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" 
                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Show/Hide
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
              <a role="menuitem" class="dropdown-item"  href="#">Show Grid</a><br>
              <a role="menuitem" class="dropdown-item"  href="#">Show eMail</a><br>
              <a role="menuitem" class="dropdown-item"  href="#">Show Lat/Lon</a><br>
              <a role="menuitem" class="dropdown-item"  href="#">Show Last Name</a><br>
              <a role="menuitem" class="dropdown-item"  href="#">Show TOD</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button id="time" class=" btn btn-info navbar-btn " type="button" onClick="TimeLine();" >Time Line</button>

        <button id="closelog" class=" btn btn-danger navbar-btn closenet "  type="button" value="Close Net" oncontextmenu="rightclickundotimeout();return false;">Close Net</button>    


    </div> <!-- end container fluid -->
</nav>

<ul  id="txtHint"></ul> 
            <div id="netids"></div>
    <br><br><br>
            <div id="actLog" class="hidden">net goes here</div>
```

Comment: make separate id's instead of separate classes

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you want me to do this. I have changed the code to <ul id="allnets" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ALLNETS"> and the other to <div id="showstuff" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="SHOWSTUFF"> but it made no difference to the problem.